# SQL extracting hour and minute from date into a single column

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a column in the format YYYY-MM-DDBHH:MI:SS and I wish to extract just the hour and minutes from this into a column. Currently on the code they are using

```
 Extract(HOUR From table) AS HR
, Extract(MINUTE From table) AS MN
```

but this outputs them into 2 columns. I'm new to SQL so is there an easier way to extract hour and minutes into one column in the format HH:MI.

Thanks

Comment: Which RDMBS are you using? I'm presuming MySQL as you are using `EXTRACT`

Comment: I'm using Teradata

Comment: @MartinParkin: `extrac(... from ..)` is standard ANSI SQL, not specific to MySQL

Comment: Can you concat using `Extract(HOUR From table) AS HR + ":" + Extract(MINUTE From table) AS MN`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name And yet it isn't present in at all in SQL Server and some other RDBMS, but is widely documented and used in MySQL, hence the (incorrect) assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Teradata, simply concatenate the output from each of the functions to give the answer:

```
Extract(HOUR From table) || ':' || Extract(MINUTE From table) AS OUTPUT
```

Comment: The output for this has massive spaces in the middle as such:          21:          3. Anyway to remove the spaces and put it into date time format?

Comment: You need to pad the number with zeros, try: `TRIM(Extract(MINUTE From table) (format '99'))`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about teradata but something like this.

```
SELECT CONCAT(Extract(HOUR From table),Extract(MINUTE From table)) as HRandMI
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got a Timestamp the easiest way to get a `HH:MI` string is:

```
to_char(mycol, 'HH24:MI')
```